# Reading an image file into bitmap from sdcard, why am I getting a NullPointerException?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-image

How can I read an image file into bitmap from sdcard?

```
 _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();  

System.out.println("pathhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh1111111112222222 " + _path);  
_path= _path + "/" + "flower2.jpg";  
System.out.println("pathhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh111111111 " + _path);  
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options );
```

I am getting a NullPointerException for bitmap. It means that the bitmap is null. But I have an image ".jpg" file stored in sdcard as "flower2.jpg". What's the problem?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

The MediaStore API is probably throwing away the alpha channel (i.e. decoding to RGB565). If you have a file path, just use BitmapFactory directly, but tell it to use a format that preserves alpha:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
selected_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

or

http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

Comment: what is `selected_photo` here?

Comment: Hi! The image saved in the Albums is 3840x2160 but the image uploaded to the server via this method is of 1080x1920

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar it may be an ImageView where you can display the decoded file.

Answer (score 31):

It works:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

Answer (score 29):

Try this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
File f = new File(_path);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}         
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 6):

I wrote the following code to convert an image from sdcard to a Base64 encoded string to send as a JSON object.And it works great:

```
String filepath = "/sdcard/temp.png";
File imagefile = new File(filepath);
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , baos);    
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```