# Android store bitmap and get bitmap from internal storage

Tags: android, file, bitmap

```
String fileName;

private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp) {
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
       out = new FileOutputStream(name + ".jpeg");
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
       try{
           out.close();
       } catch(Throwable ignore) {}
}
}
private void readFile() {

}
```

Now I need to read the file. 
Just please help write the "readFile()" method fully depending on my code.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading an image file into bitmap from sdcard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710515/reading-an-image-file-into-bitmap-from-sdcard)

Comment: I don't want to read from sdcard

Comment: Do you need to do that with muliple images? maybe you can store them on SQLite DB

Answer (score 0):

Try with following

```
File f=new File(path, name + ".jpeg");
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
```

Have a look on the [Saving and Reading Bitmaps/Images from Internal memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-images-to-internal-memory-in-android)

Comment: Depending on my code should I do so?   File f = new File( ,fileName + ".jpeg");? and in place of path what should I write?