# Android Bitmap on Canvas from External File

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawable

I use the following code to get a bitmap from the resources folder put it into a drawable and paint it to the canvas

```
 Drawable f = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.harris1);
 f.setBounds(a,120,a+200,270);
 f.draw(canvas);
```

I want to be able to get the bitmap from my pictures directory on my device and paint it on the canvas

I get the filepath as follows

```
 File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
 String name = "harris1.jpg";
 File file = new File(path, name );
 String fileName = String.format("%s/" + name, path);
```

in this instance filename is equal to "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/harris1.jpg"

How do i change the line

Drawable f = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.harris);

to use the filname of the picture on the device?

Any Help Appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, ...);
```

Comment: I tried Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(a,120,a+200,270), rectangle, null); but it has a error under he word rectangle what value is rectangle?

Comment: Try to put there two equal rects new Rect(a,120,a+200,270)

Comment: sorry throws an error 06-04 06:13:28.206: E/AndroidRuntime(9993): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 06:13:28.206: E/AndroidRuntime(9993):  at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1083)

Comment: This works put the rectangle in the right place and size but it blank and doesnt show bitmap Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/harris1.jpg");
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(a,120,a+200,270), new Rect(a,120,a+200,270), null);

Comment: This does it canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,null, new Rect(a,120,a+200,270), null); made the source rect null –

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitmapFactory` there's an example you can follow

[Reading an image file into bitmap from sdcard, why am I getting a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710515/reading-an-image-file-into-bitmap-from-sdcard-why-am-i-getting-a-nullpointerexc)

Answer (score 0):

You might like this bit of code:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
BitmapDrawable imagePath = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/harris1.jpg");
myImageView.setImageBitmap(imagePath.getBitmap());
```

Comment: I dont have an imageview Im trying to print to a canvas which in turn is saved as a PDF using it from resources works fine just cant work out how to use an image from the device