# Force close within Android Wear component

Tags: android, wear-os, forceclose

My app has been working quite happily with Android Wear support for the last two years or so.  Following an update to Android Webview, I'm getting force closes in some circumstances when running my app.  The force close is within the Android Wear component though.  My software hasn't changed (and I don't think I'm using a Webview at all, though Wear may be I suppose).  I'm not really sure how to go about debugging this, other than keep on reporting the issue via Android and wait for Google to fix it (if indeed the bug is within Android Wear or Android Webview itself).  Here's the stack trace.  Does anyone have any ideas what's causing it please?  Any help gratefully received.

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: I think this might actually be something to do with a notification my app creates.  While that isn't specifically directed at Wear, I imagine the Wear API will attempt to replicate that on the watch.  That might explain the references to the Notification Bridger, and why the subsequent force close is within the Wear runtime.

Comment: Have you officially reported the bug to Google?

Comment: I found here a questions that en counter this kind or error message. So just check it if you can get any idea on how to solve thi kind of problem. SO question [32267265](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267265) and [33343191](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343191)

Comment: @ KENdi - many thanks.  I think the distinction with both those questions is that the stack trace points to a user application causing the fault.  The stack trace above lists packages which are wholly within Android.

Comment: @ String - Yes, I'll do that.  I reported it via the dialog you get on the phone after a force close, but no harm in reporting directly.

Comment: This seems to be a bug introduced by the most recent Android Wear update on 23rd March 2017. I downgraded and the force close message has stopped. I also think there's a memory leak in the current version - my phone completely grinds to a halt when the most recent version is installed. Downgraded version is fine.