# Scaling jpg image from Bitmap.compress android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am converting, bitmap to jpeg using

```
val file = File(filePath)
val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
profileImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos)
```

The jpeg looks okay. But its very tiny. I thought it was the jpeg lossy nature but when I tried to convert bitmap into png, it also came down to same size. Is there a way to increase the size of jpeg, compressed from bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use createScaledBitmap to scale up your bitmap before converting to jpeg, try passing true as the filter boolean to get better results. [(You might want to decode the bitmap from the file first)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710690/2483399).

[createScaledBitmap documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))