# bitmap.createscaledbitmap is not work in marshmallows

Tags: android, bitmap, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am creating run time image view and set width and height according to image, Its work perfect below the android marshmallows but its not working in marshmallows.

I am check my image is not null and bitmap is also not null. same code is working fine and show image according to me.. but when this code is run marshmallows then given error. I have also given all permition. erroe for this line  **image.getMeasuredWidth()** this line is given error

this is my Code -

```
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, image.getMeasuredWidth(), image.getMeasuredWidth(), false));
```

this code has given error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:610)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an image file into bitmap from sdcard, why am I getting a NullPointerException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710515/reading-an-image-file-into-bitmap-from-sdcard-why-am-i-getting-a-nullpointerexc)

Comment: same code is working fine in below android 6

Comment: I am check image is not null

Comment: Man, can you check where do you add the getMeasuredWidth() method, maybe the view still isn't drawn yet.

Comment: ya this method 'getMeasuredWidth()' is given null exception. in only marshmallow

Comment: hello my Question is not duplicate. my problem is only marshmallow. give me solution.... I have also check given link but its not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this answer.

when click the camera button.

```
public void getPhotoFromCamera() {

    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
       Toast.makeText(this,"camera permition",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"1111111111",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "IMG_"
                            + File.separator
                            + ".jpg"
            );

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            try {
               File mediaFile = File.createTempFile(
                        "IMG_" + timeStamp,  /* prefix */
                        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                        mediaStorageDir      /* directory */
                );
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 100);

                Log.e("STRING",mediaFile.getPath()+"    String   "+mediaFile);

                fileUri=Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and add this also

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("String", resultCode + "   " + requestCode);


        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            Log.e("Camera111", "2222222222" );
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            camera = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            Log.e("Camera111", "" + camera);
            setimage(camera);
        }
    }

    private void setimage(Bitmap bitmap) {

        if (text == null) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.restro_image)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            text.setMaxHeight(text.getMeasuredWidth());
            if (picturePath != null) {

                text.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, text.getMeasuredWidth(), text.getMeasuredWidth(), false));
            } else {
                text.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, text.getMeasuredWidth(), text.getMeasuredWidth(), false));
//                text.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this is work for you.