# What is the best practice to pre catch images for android list?

Tags: android, caching, picasso, android-image

currently i am loading the images even if user not scrolled to view so when he will the image will be load faster from Picasso caching , on the list contractor

```
private void createImageCatch(ArrayList<Article> items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Article article = (Article) items.get(i);
            if (article.getImageUrl() != null
                    && article.getImageUrl().length() > 0)
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(article.getImageUrl())
                        .fetch();
    }
}
```

this is working perfect , the images are ready to go even if user scroll fast , but is this the best way to do this ?

IMPROVE UPDATE - added static boolean to make sure this method called only once , if images was added on server side this is not big deal for few images to be loaded on scroll time as long must of them already in cach.

Comment: depends on ImageView size && ListView items count

Comment: I do not see it as a right way, pre-fetching the data that you do not need yet is way to overkill.

Comment: small images , about 30 . i am also not see this is the best way this is why i am asking . i want to avoid blank image even for very short time

Comment: Having a blank image for a short period of time is not a big deal for users apart from that you can use placeholder image.

Comment: this is a very big application , i want it to be as smooth as can be...

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the [Volley library](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)? It has a special `ImageView` that downloads and caches images for you.

Replace the `ImageView` in your XML with something like this:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
 />
```

And load your image with

```
NetworkImageView photo = (NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
photo.setImageUrl("http://someurl.com/image.png", mImageLoader);
```

You do need to set up your `ImageLoader`, so create some fields:

```
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
```

and initialize them in your `onCreate`:

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        mCache.put(url, bitmap);
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return mCache.get(url);
    }
});
```

Source: [Setting up the Android Google Volley ImageLoader for NetworkImageView](http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/)

Comment: but Picasso does it for me also so what is the different ? i have consider Glide also but the result will be the same if i understand current . i am thinking maybe to do my solution but only for images in position near the current position . if user in 10 position maybe i will get only next images instead all at once . i will update .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse ~30 small images, you can keep them in the memory as soft reference of `Bitmaps`, and recycle all after leaving `Fragment` or `Activity` with `ListView`.

---

For example your `ImageView` has size 55dp x 55dp, and there are 30 rows with images.

---

**DisplayManager**:

```
public static DP_55;//55 dp to px, do not count it each time, define it!
public static defineSize(Activity activity)
{
     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
     DP_55 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 55, metrics);
}
```

**Your Activity or Fragment**:

```
public HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();
```

---

Load images from [File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710690/3226984) or [Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394484/3226984) as `Bitmap`, scale to your size (55 dp) and put to the dictionary:

```
if (!bitmaps.containsKey(urlOrPath)) {
     //Load 'bitmap' and put to dictionary:
     bitmaps.put(urlOrPath, new SoftReference<>(
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        bitmap,
                        DisplayManager.DP_55, DisplayManager.DP_55, true)));
}
else //Just reuse it!
     iv_image.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(urlOrPath).get());
```

---

**How to recycle it**:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>> iterator = bitmaps.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       iterator.next().getValue().get().recycle();
       iterator.remove();
}
```

You won't get out of 40MB limit (if `ImageView` size is small and there are < 50 rows), and loading images after scrolling maximum fast.
Otherwise use ImageLoaders (Glide, Picasso, etc).