# Read all photos from the gallery

Tags: android

I am trying to read all the photos which I put to the sdcard via Android Device Monitor, I can get the path such as /storage/emulated/0/lemon.jpg

Could you please tell me how I could convert this photo into bitmap?

Comment: Unclear. A jpg file actually **is** a bitmap*ped* picture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710515/reading-an-image-file-into-bitmap-from-sdcard-why-am-i-getting-a-nullpointerexc

Comment: `A jpg file actually is a bitmapped picture` ?????? OP means the Bitmap class.

Comment: @greenapps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap ... 'nuff said.

Comment: @ModularSynth, Well nice to know but not very helpfull if one wants a Bitmap instance for a jpg file.

Comment: @greenapps Then the OP should be a bit more specific, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Android 4.4 (API level 19) and above you can use [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html). Open a document using SAF, get Uri on onActivityResult() and use Uri to open image and turn it into a Bitmap.

Once you have the URI for a document, you can open it or do whatever else you want to do with it.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: I try this method, but when I set the imageView, i get this error,                          Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference